# How do I configure NServiceBus (v6.2) using AzureServiceBusTransport to not create topology

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

Does anyone know how to configure NServiceBus (v6.2) using the AzureServiceBusTransport to not attempt to create namespaces?

I'd like to configure NServiceBus the use a connection string which only has permissions to send (the queue's should already be there and if not an error is more appropriate than creation) but whenever I configure it this way I get the following error:

`Pre start-up check failed: Configured to create topology, but have no manage rights for the following namespace(s): xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

This error message suggests the functionality is configurable but having looked through the code and the documentation for the mechanism I can't find it.

Many thanks

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I answered my own question - a bug was raised against the AzureServiceBusTransport and subsequently fixed a little while ago:
https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AzureServiceBus/issues/528

As the bug says upgrading to version 7.1.8 or 7.2.3 and not enabling installers fixes the issue.